# Show button in angular

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to create one button like pre, when ever I will onclick of pre button (`getPrevWeek`) will show the Next button, how can I create on this angular.

Note: Here ##hide/show is working. i need only for show

Blow my angular html code:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="prevJoinDateValid" class="btn btn-info btn-spacing" (click)="getPrevWeek()" id="prev">Prev</button>
<button *ngIf="isShownnext" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-spacing" (click)="getNextWeek()" id="next">Next</button>
```

angular ts file:

```
isShownnext: boolean = false ;

getPrevWeek() {
   this.isShownnext = ! this.isShownnext;
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time really understanding, but I think you want to do `this.isShownnext = true` instead of flipping the value.

Comment: Hi ShamPooSham ,,,Exactly same on this thank you working fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set the value of this.isShownnext to true
this.isShownnext = true

Answer (score 0):

Use NgIf condition for the button you want to hide and make it true on other Button Click
Example:

```
<button (click)="ButtonClick()">pre</button>
<button *ngIf="mShowbutton">next</button>

ButtonClick()
{
 this.mShowbutton=true;
}
```